# Return Index of Minimum Row for Each Column of Matrix

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose I have a matrix like the example below called `m1`:

```r
m1<-matrix(6:1,nrow=3,ncol=2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    6    3
[2,]    5    2
[3,]    4    1
```

How do I get the index row for the minimum value of each column?
I know `which.min()` will return the column index value for each row.

The output should be: 3 and 3 because the minimum for column [,1] is 4 corresponding to row [3,] and the minimum for column [,2] is 1 corresponding row [3,].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we need column wise index use `apply` with `MARGIN=2` and apply the `which.min`

```
apply(m1, 2, which.min)
#[1] 3 3
```

If 1 column at a time is needed:

```
apply(as.matrix(m1[,1, drop = FALSE]), 2, which.min)
```

If we check `?Extract`, the default usage is

> x[i, j, ... , drop = TRUE]
>
> drop - For matrices and arrays. If TRUE the result is coerced to the lowest possible dimension (see the examples). This only works for extracting elements, not for the replacement. See drop for further details.

To avoid getting dimensions dropped, use `drop = FALSE`

If we need the min values of each row

```
do.call(pmin, as.data.frame(m1))
```

Or

```
apply(m1, 2, min)
```

Or

```
library(matrixStats)
rowMins(m1)
```

#### data

```
m1 <- matrix(6:1,nrow=3,ncol=2)
```

Comment: thanks, I might be missing the application, doesn't max.col return the maximum (in your answer minimum) of each row in the matrix?

Comment: @Mark I updated with the description about the issue you raised

Comment: one last question, is there a way to get the results 1 column at a time?

Comment: @Mark For that case you need `m1[, 1, drop = FA:LSE]` because if you check `?Extract`, it would drop the dimensions when there is a single column/row (default is `drop = TRUE`)