# Return Index Row Number of N Minimum/Maximum Value for Each Column of Matrix

Tags: r, matrix, data-manipulation

An extension of this post: [Return Index of Minimum Row for Each Column of Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56202749/return-index-of-minimum-row-for-each-column-of-matrix)

Suppose I have a matrix like the example below called `m1`:

```r
m1<-matrix(6:1,nrow=3,ncol=2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    6    3
[2,]    5    2
[3,]    4    1
```

How do I Return Index Row Number of N lowest Value for Each Column of Matrix?

For example, if I wanted the index row of the 2nd lowest row in column [,1] the row index would be 2 [2,] because the 2nd highest value in column [,1] is 5.

If I wanted the 3rd lowest row in column [,1] the row index would be 1 [1,] because 6 is the 3rd highest value in column [,1].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the index of the highest and lowest values

```
apply(m1, 2, which.max)
apply(m1, 2, which.min)
```

If we are interested in 2nd highest, 2nd lowest etc

```
apply(m1, 2, function(x) order(x)[2])
```

Or use `sort` with `index.return = TRUE`

```
apply(m1, 2, function(x) sort(x, index.return = TRUE))
```

and then extract the index of interest

```
apply(m1, 2, function(x) {i1 <- sort(x, index.return = TRUE)$ix
                i1[i1 < 3]
     })
```

If we need the row index

```
getrowIndexEachCol <- function(mat, n, isMax = TRUE) {
   if(!isMax) mat <- -mat
   apply(mat, 2, function(x) {i1 <- rank(x)
            i1[i1 <= n]
       })
  }
 getrowIndexEachCol(m1, 2)
```

The difference would be noticed using a different dataset

```
m2 <- cbind(c(7, 3, 5, 8, 11), c(4, 8, 6, 5, 3))
getrowIndexEachCol(m2, 3)
```